# (quasi) convexity $\frac{x}{y}$

Tags: convex-analysis

Hej,

I have the function $\frac{x}{y}$ on the domain $R_{++}$.
The Hessian matrix is - as I have calculated it - positive semidefinite.
But I'm not really sure, if the function is really convex at all on the domain.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The function is quasilinear, but I'm not sure how to show it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something went wrong with your calculation, because the Hessian matrix 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1/y^2 \\ -1/y^2 & 2/y^3
\end{pmatrix}
$$
has negative determinant.

There is a similar function with positive semidefinite Hessian in the positive quadrant, namely $v(x,y)=x^2/y$. The Hessian is 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2/y & -2x/y^2 \\ -2x/y^2 & 2x^2/y^3
\end{pmatrix} 
= \frac{2}{y^3}\langle x,y \rangle \otimes \langle x,y \rangle \ge 0
$$
Given its simple form, I wonder if there is any "obvious" reason for the convexity of $v$.